# How to switch between different statements in a loop

Tags: java, loops

Im trying to figure out how to make a loop over two things for example Players and check if each of them is active and if so they should do different things.

It should check first if there is a winner, if not the first player should do his move and check if he won by doing that move. After the first player did his move and did not win yet the second player should do his move and of course test if he won. If no one has won yet the first player should do the next move and so on.

That is whats going through my mind right now.

```
boolean playerOne = true;
boolean playerTwo = false;
boolean haveWinner = false;


while(haveWinner == false) {

    if (playerOne == true & playerTwo == false) {
        /*do something */
        playerOne = false;
        playerTwo = true;
    } else if (playerOne == false & playerTwo == true) {
        /* do something */
        playerOne = true;
        playerTwo = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No ones turn");
    }
}
```

I know that this wont work like that since the first If request is true and the else if wont even come through. But how can i make that it basically switch everytime?

Comment: Not the most beautiful code, but i don't see why this shouldnt work. Answer by Eran shows a better way. You could also use `switch()` that would be better if you want to add more players. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `playerTwo` variable. Just toggle the `playerOne` variable to determine if it's player one's turn or not (in which case it would be player two's turn).

This makes your loop as simple as :

```
boolean playerOne = true;
boolean haveWinner = false;

while (!haveWinner) {   
    if (playerOne) {
        /*player one's turn - do something */
        playerOne = false;
    } else {
        /* player two's turn - do something */
        playerOne = true;
    }
}
```

or you could even save one line of code with :

```
boolean playerOne = true;
boolean haveWinner = false;

while (!haveWinner) {   
    if (playerOne) {
        /*player one's turn - do something */
    } else {
        /* player two's turn - do something */
    }
    playerOne = !playerOne;
}
```

Comment: @DeanJ. It toggles the value of `playerOne` at the end of each iteration. If it was true it becomes false and vice versa.

Comment: I like that one alot, looks clean. Thanks again.